# keras tensorflow metric is loss always calculated

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I came across this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data). It defines `METRICS` as below. My questions are

```
METRICS = [
          keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
          keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
          keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
          keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
          keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
          keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
          keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
          keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    ]

Train on 182276 samples, validate on 45569 samples
    Epoch 1/100
    182276/182276 [==============================] - 2s 12us/sample - loss: 0.0139 - tp: 7.0000 - fp: 124.0000 - tn: 181835.0000 - fn: 310.0000 - accuracy: 0.9976 - precision: 0.0534 - recall: 0.0221 - auc: 0.7262 - val_loss: 0.0074 - val_tp: 4.0000 - val_fp: 0.0000e+00 - val_tn: 45492.0000 - val_fn: 73.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9984 - val_precision: 1.0000 - val_recall: 0.0519 - val_auc: 0.8742
    Epoch 2/100
    182276/182276 [==============================] - 0s 3us/sample - loss: 0.0076 - tp: 91.0000 - fp: 30.0000 - tn: 181929.0000 - fn: 226.0000 - accuracy: 0.9986 - precision: 0.7521 - recall: 0.2871 - auc: 0.8828 - val_loss: 0.0053 - val_tp: 39.0000 - val_fp: 7.0000 - val_tn: 45485.0000 - val_fn: 38.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9990 - val_precision: 0.8478 - val_recall: 0.5065 - val_auc: 0.8761
    Epoch 3/100
    182276/182276 [==============================] - 0s 3us/sample - loss: 0.0064 - tp: 146.0000 - fp: 36.0000 - tn: 181923.0000 - fn: 171.0000 - accuracy: 0.9989 - precision: 0.8022 - recall: 0.4606 - auc: 0.8981 - val_loss: 0.0049 - val_tp: 45.0000 - val_fp: 7.0000 - val_tn: 45485.0000 - val_fn: 32.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9991 - val_precision: 0.8654 - val_recall: 0.5844 - val_auc: 0.8828
```

1. Why loss is displayed after each epoch if it is not part of `METRICS`. Is `loss` a default option? would it be present for regression or multi class classification too?
2. Keras displays each `METRICS` for training and validation data. Is it because when we fit the model we provide validation data `validation_data=(val_features, val_labels)`? if we dont provide validation data, would that give an error as it couldnt print metrics for validation data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - It is default, unless you put `verbose=0` then there is nothing. Yes in all case it is present

2 - Yes, if you don't provide validation_data then you won't have anything on val metrics

Answer (score 1):

1) The loss is the training objective of your neural net and thus you always require it, regardless of a regression or classification problem.
It is displayed by default in Keras. [Keras Loss Documentation](https://keras.io/losses/)

Metrics are used to evaluate your model, hence you can define more than one.
[Keras Metrics Documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/)

2) If you do not provide validation data, Keras has, as the name implies, no data to validate your model on and it will throw an Error.

Comment: If you do not provide validation data then it just won't run validation on your data, it won't give an error